# Playing Audio with DirectX 9 C++

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm a beginner to DirectX 9 and the Win32 API, can anyone give me any pointers about how to play wav files with this setup?

Comment: Why are you using DirectX 9 rather than Direct3D 11? If you use Direct3D 11, you can use the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) which includes a simple wrapper for XAudio2. See the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) to get started.

Comment: DirectX 9 is the API I got a book on for Christmas

Comment: If you just want to play files and not messing with sound effect and buffers, media foundation is an option as well as it supports ordinary media format.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use Win32 API then you can use PlaySound API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

```
::PlaySound(L"hello.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

DirectSound has already been deprecated so you should use XAudio2 to play sound. Here's how to play sound with XAudio2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415787(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Asesh, XAudio2 is working very well!

Comment: But PlaySound cannot play multiple soundtracks simultaneously! How do you guys handle this?

Comment: @programmer Create threads and call `PlaySound` from those threads to play multiple sound tracks. It doesn't support multiple files